# How To Process Many Files Quickly In C# Desktop App Without Freezing App

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have around 500 JPEG images on a removable media device.  My desktop app (.NET 4.5) is one Winforms form that currently contains FileInfo objects for these images in a List by using Directory.EnumerateFiles.  No problem there and very quick.  The main intent is to take all these files and upload them to an S3 bucket while also doing a bit of logging via a REST API call and reporting progress back to the user for all the files, and of course when the whole file set is done uploading.

How can I take this List of FileInfo objects and process them the most efficiently while also updating a progress bar and allowing the user to move the form without it freezing?  Doing things in a simple ForEach loop obviously is slow.  Processing each file involves uploading the image to an S3 bucket if certain metadata fields exist, writing to a REST API to store a record in a SQL database, then updating the UI to notify the user of progress as well as flagging the file in a visual data grid as "done". I can do all that code fine, but unsure of how to go through this list of files simultaneously while not causing UI issues on the form.

My real question: I heard many mention Parallel.ForEach, TPL, using Tasks, Async/Await, and I'm struggling to understand which is the best option for my use case, and how to go about it for updating the UI/progressbar without problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# .Net Freeze while iterating through large number of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38083668/c-sharp-net-freeze-while-iterating-through-large-number-of-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this is an *IO bound workload*, and your libraries probably support `async`, then the *async and await pattern* is the way to go. This will allow efficient use of *thread-pool threads* while the `OS` deals with the *IO Completion ports*, meaning while work is being offloaded to IO bound operations the thread-pool can reuse this valuable resource while the *Pattern* also manages *continuations* and the *synchronization context* so you can update the *UI*

Since `Parallel.For/ForEach` does not support the *async await pattern* and will be ultimately inefficient, the simplest way to go would be `Task.Run` and `Task.WhenAll` with `async` methods.

However, i would also take a look at `ActionBlock<T>` in the Microsoft *TPL DataFlow library* This will give you the best of both worlds of being able to use the *async and await pattern*, and also limit the max degrees of parallelism.

Another option would be *reactive extensions*, which has all these goodies as well